# How can I move a village?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I've created a FlatLand world in creative mode with the intention of creating my own terrain.  The problem is I wind up having village that lower in elevation than I want them to be.  I am trying to recreate the village by taking each block and moving it up the required number of steps so it is on the new terrain, but I am running into an issue - I can't find some of the items I need under the creative mode inventory system.  Some of the things I can't figure out how to move:

- whatever block goes under pressure plates that make the appearance of a table leg, also used for wooden posts
- chests
- carrots
- potatos
- another crop I can't tell what it is, it sorta looks like bamboo

I know when I first started to play it would annoyingly tell me what everything I looked at was when I wasn't interested, and now that I am I can't figure out how to get this information.

Is there an easier way to move an entire village other than re-create it from scratch?  And where can I find the items I am missing?  I was hoping I could just take them out of my environment and into my inventory, but I can't figure out how.  All my experience is in creative mode building things and digging, so I am hoping I won't have to figure out how to actually craft or grow things!

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the Xbox version(s), and looking up screenshots has shown me that it's different enough from the PC version that I can't be certain. However; 1) is a fence, when not connected to the side of another fence or a solid block it is just a post. If the screenshots I found reflect the current XBox versions; you might be able to find them under the miscellaneous tab. 2) chests should be under the same tab as fences. 3/4) Carrots and potatoes should be under the food tab, and can be planed as crops by placing them on farmland (grass/dirt tilled with a hoe)

Comment: 5) is either wheat or sugarcane. To replant wheat, the seeds should be under the materials tab, and like carrots and potatoes they need tilled farmland. Sugarcane (which looks the most like the bamboo you describe) needs to be placed on either dirt, grass or sand, and the block it's placed on must be directly next to water.

Comment: @TrentHawkins I found the fence and chest, but for seeds I only see wheat, melon, pumpkin and cocoa.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Oh I see, apparently some foods aren't seeds, you get actual "carrots" and "plant" them for example.